Show YouTube Shorts in each channel's "Videos" tab
Short videos ("YouTube Shorts") aren't listed in a YouTube channel's Videos tab, but are listed separately in the Shorts tab. That can be very confusing.
Is there a way to list Shorts among the videos?
For example, a userscript may fetch the list of Shorts in the background and insert them into the list of videos.
